# tinymce including plugins causing error

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am trying to include a few simple plugins for the tinymce editor. The pagebreak and print to be more specific and as soon as I do it spits an error out two errors in the editor_plugin.js at the first line. Now I have no control over this specific file since this is a default file so I am assuming that I am doing something in my file to trigger it.

The error is this

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

and my code that inits the tinymce looks like this

```
 tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "biography",
        theme: "advanced",
        width: "90%",
        height: "300px",
         plugins : "pagebreak, print",
        pagebreak_separator : "<!-- my page break -->",
       theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,hr,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent, indent,|",
       theme_advanced_buttons2: "removeformat,forecolor,code,|,print",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "center",
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,
        cleanup_on_startup: true,
        fix_list_elements: false,
        fix_nesting: false,
        fix_table_elements: false,
        paste_use_dialog: true,
         height: "500px",
         width:"100%",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    });
```

Is there any way I can fix this error so I can use those plugins?